# SQL Query behaving inappropriately.

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, duplicates

I'm a newbie developer but I certainly know that a script once written is supposed to behave a certain way but in the following use case, that's apparently not happening.

I've created a script with INSERT INTO SELECT statements which are supposed to filter out the duplicates and throw the differentials into a STAGING table and keep record of past 7 days in a STAGING2 table. I've SQL jobs running in the backend to make sure my scripts run every few minutes. Now, the weird thing that's happened once before and now is that the jobs keep working fine, my FACT tables get populated properly with no duplicates but suddenly JOBS start failing as somehow duplicates get into the system. I'll share the code below if anyone can help. ( This is the same code which has been working proper for months).

```
USE [PowerBI]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [ALJAZEERA\Naeemf].[sp_fact_ticket]    Script Date: 11/4/2018 1:44:59 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [ALJAZEERA\Naeemf].[sp_fact_ticket]
AS
BEGIN
truncate table fact.ticket
insert into fact.ticket
select 
[ticket_type],
[Assigned_to],
[caller],
[Due_Date],
[Ticket_Number],
[active],
[Approval_History],
[Duration_Seconds],
[Assigned to],
[Email Address (Assigned to)],
[Assignment Group],
[Business_Duration],
[Closed By Email Address],
[Link],
[Location],
[Made_SLA],
[Opened By Full Name],
[Opened By Email Address],
[Opened at date],
[Reassignment_Count],
[Service_Offering],
[Short_Description],
[State Name],
[u_Type],
[Created On Date],
[u_Comments_Updated],
[u_One_To_One_Training],
[u_Priority_Changed],
[Vendor],
[Vendor_Number],
[Caller Primary Group],
[Opened By Primary Group],
[Closed By Primary Group],
[Category],
[CMDB_CI],
[Opened By Job Title],
[Opened Month Name],
[Opened Year],
[Opened at Day Name],
[Opened Quarter],
[Closed at year],
[Closed at month name],
[Closed at Date],
[Closed at quarter],
[Contact_Type],
[Sharepoint_Request],
[SD_Request],
[Priority Name],
[Assigned to Primary Group],
[closed by],
[Sys_ID],
[u_Confidential],
[close_notes],
[u_bomgar]
from
(
select  'Incident' as ticket_type, [assigned to] AS Assigned_to,[Caller ID Name] AS caller, number AS Ticket_Number,active as active,[Approval_History],Calendar_STC as Duration_Seconds,[Assigned to],[Email Address (Assigned to)],[Assignment Group],
Business_Duration,[Closed By Email Address],Due_Date,Link,[Location],Made_SLA,[Opened By Full Name],[Opened By Email Address],[Opened at date],Reassignment_Count,Service_Offering,Short_Description,[State Name],u_Type,[Created On Date],u_Comments_Updated,
[u_One_To_One_Training],u_Priority_Changed,u_Vendor as Vendor,u_Vendor_Number as Vendor_Number,[Caller Primary Group],[Opened By Primary Group],[Closed By Primary Group],Category,CMDB_CI,[Opened By Job Title],[Opened Month Name],[Opened Year],[Opened at date] as OD1,[Opened at Day Name],
[Opened Quarter],[Closed at year],[Closed at month name],[Closed at Date],[Closed at quarter],Contact_Type,null as Sharepoint_Request,null as SD_Request,[Priority Name],[Assigned to Primary Group],[closed by],[Sys_ID],u_confidential,
close_notes,[u_bomgar]
from [ALJAZEERA\Naeemf].[Incidents Hierarchy View]
UNION
select  'Task', [assigned to], NULL,  number,active,approval,calendar_stc,[Assigned To],[Assigned to Email],[Assignment Group],business_duration,[Closed By Email],due_date,Link,[Location],made_sla,[Opened By],[Opened By Email],opened_at,reassignment_count,[business_service],short_description,[State],sys_class_name,[opened_at],u_comments_updated,
u_one_to_one_training,u_priority_changed,u_vendor,u_vendor_number,null,[Opened By Primary Group],[Closed By Primary Group],u_first_category,[CMDB CI],[Opened By Title],[Opened at Month Name],[Opened at Year],opened_at,[Opened at Day Name],
[Opened at Quarter],[Closed at year],[Closed at Month Name],[Closed At],[Closed at Quarter],null,null,null,[Priority],[Assigned To Primary Group],[closed by name],null,u_confidential,close_notes,u_bomgar
from [ALJAZEERA\Naeemf].[Catalog Tasks Hierarchy View]
Union
select  'Request', null,null,number,active,approval,calendar_stc,[Assigned to],[Assigned to email],[Assignment Group],business_duration,[Closed By Email],due_date,link,[Location],made_sla,[Opened By],[Opened By Email],opened_at,reassignment_count,Service_Offering,short_description,request_state,sys_class_name,sys_created_on,u_comments_updated,
u_one_to_one_training,u_priority_changed,u_vendor,u_vendor_number,null, [Opened By Primary Group],[Closed By Primary Group],null,CMDB_CI,[Opened By Title],[Opened Month Name],[Opened Year],opened_at,[Opened WeekdayName],[Opened Quarter]
,[Closed Year],[Closed Month Name],closed_at,[Closed Quarter],contact_type,u_sharepoint_request,u_sd_request,null,null,[closed by],[sys_id],null,close_notes,null
from [ALJAZEERA\Naeemf].[Requests Hierarchy View]
Union
select  'Change',[assigned to],null,number,active,[approval_history],null,[Assigned To],[Assigned to Email],[Assignment Group],[business_duration],[Closed by Email],[due_date],null,[location],
[made_sla],[Opened By],[Opened By Email],[opened_at],[reassignment_count],[Service Offering],[short_description],[State],null,null,[u_comments_updated],[u_one_to_one_training],[u_priority_changed],
[u_vendor],[u_vendor_number],null,[Opened By Primary Group],[Closed by Primary Group],[category],[CMDB_CI],[Opened By Title],[Opened Month Name],[Opened Year],[opened_at] as OD1,null,
[Opened Quarter],[Closed Year],[Closed Month Name],[closed_at],[Closed Quarter],null,null,null,null,[Assigned to Primary Group],[Closed By],[sys_id],u_confidential,close_notes,null
from dbo.Fact_Change
Union
select  'Problem',[Assigned to],null,number,active,approval,null,[Assigned to],[Assigned to Email],[Assignment Group],business_duration,[Closed By Email],due_date,link,Null,made_sla,[Opened By],null,[Created Date],reassignment_count,Service_Offering,short_description,[state],sys_class_name,[Created Date],u_comments_updated,
u_one_to_one_training,u_priority_changed,u_vendor,u_vendor_number,null,null,null,u_category,CMDB_CI,[Opened By Title],[Created Month Name],[Created Year],[Created Date],[Created Day Name],[Created Quarter],[Closed Year],[Closed Month Name],[Closed at Date],
[Closed Quarter],null,null,null,[Priority],null,[closed by],[sys_id],u_confidential,close_notes,null
from [ALJAZEERA\Naeemf].[Problems Hierarchy View]) a
END
```

Appreciate all the help that I can get.

Thanks.

Comment: What even are the unique columns? What's in your jobs? There's nowhere enough info to help here

Comment: Hi Nick. The unique identifier column is [sys_id].

Comment: To add to it, there are no duplicates to the tables unioned. I've verified all of them. It's only here in the fact.ticket table where all the others tables are being unioned that the duplicates have started to appear since a few days.

Comment: I've also truncated and used the SELECT DISTINCT statement instead of SELECT but to no avail.

Comment: Your insert statement does not have a column list, which is bad practice, but also means we don't know which column you're loading into. Even if we knew what the data looked like. The first step to start troubleshooting is to add a column list to the insert statement.

Comment: Do you mean duplicate sys_id's are appearing? or is it some other set of columns that indicates duplicates? I doubt if I can help you but I can certainly help you analyse it

Comment: Oh now I see Sys_id at the end but you should still have a column list in the insert

Comment: Sys_id is hard coded to `null` when you select from `[Catalog Tasks Hierarchy View]`. Is that the duplicate you're talking about?

Comment: I will add that to your question. In future please add it at the start. What you are actually saying is that you expect `Ticket_Number` to be unique but it's not. There's no clue in your question why this should be the case. Your next logical step is to identify a duplicate ticket number and inspect the four individual data sources for it

Comment: huh? You keep deleting your comments.

Comment: The following code

SELECT  count (sys_id), Ticket_Number
FROM [fact].[ticket]
group by (sys_id),ticket_number
having count(sys_id)>1

gives me the following results

(No column name) Ticket_Number
2 REQ0011041
2 REQ0011061
2 REQ0011359
2 REQ0011450
2 REQ0011637
2 REQ0011668
2 REQ0011815
2 REQ0011922

So, apparently, the issue lies in the [Requests Hierarchy View]. I'm gonna check that table now to check whether the duplicates lie in the Requests table.

Comment: Yeah Nick. I deleted a few comments It's my first time on this forum and I keep pressing ENTER which ends up pasting half comments. I am getting used to Shift+Enter now for typing in a new line.

Comment: Verified. The [Requests Hierarchy View] contains duplicates. I need to now figure out why.

Comment: So.. in summary the statement " there are no duplicates to the tables unioned. I've verified all of them" wasn't correct. The important thing to learn is that if you had explained the issue in detail at the start you would have discovered the issue. I'll vote to close this one and you may wish to ask a new question but make sure you explain in great detail and in doing so you'll probably answer your own question.

Comment: Please don't mark answers as correct if they are not correct. The issue as stated by yourself is "The [Requests Hierarchy View] contains duplicates"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your query run without the procedure itself?

Looking at the various union selects it looks like you have a cross over of columns with different datatypes/nulls overlaid. If the table structure has changed which prevents a null being entered for one of the columns this could also cause the issue you are having.

Try gutting the query out of the procedure and see if you get any results/what results you are getting.